# Linker command failed error in AppDelegate because of Google Analytics

Tags: xcode, swift, google-analytics

I'M trying to integrate Google Analytics to my Xcode project. I've added obj-c classes by using bridging header and then I've set some options in AppDelegate. After AppDelegate commands I got the following errors. How can I solve that one?

Note: Xcode recognises GAI class.

Error causing code:

```
GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true
GAI.sharedInstance().logger.logLevel = .Verbose
GAI.sharedInstance().dispatchInterval = 20
GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXXXXX-Y")
```

Errors:
[image: Errors]

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix(works for me) - Delete the 'Google Analytics' **references,not "remove to trash" option** from your project navigator, and add them again. Should work out

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to **libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a** file.